# Set default text color in a custom drop-down menu?

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm using a custom menu. How do I set the color of the default text ("Select county", "Select area") to color `#ccc`, and the color of the actual value to `#000`?

[image: The color of the Red Marina must be different from the color of the following menu]

```html
<div class="form-control>
    <div class="login-placeholder" @click="isAddShow=!isAddShow">{{ addrItem }}
    </div>
    <ul v-show="isAddShow" class="l-select-wrap">
        <li v-for="(item,i) in addSelectData" :key="i" @click="addSelectOption(item)"
            class="l-select-item">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


data:{
    isAddShow: false,
    addrItem : "Select county"
}
    addSelectData: [{
        name: "Tapie",
    },
    {
        name: "Taichung",
    },
    {
        name: "Tainan",
    },
    {
        name: "Kaohsiung",
    },
],
```

Comment: Could you use a screenshot or image to explain that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use style block or set style locally

Solution 1 : Use style block

```
<style>
     .login-placeholder{
          color:"#ccc"
     }
     .l-select-wrap{
          color:"#000"
     }
</style>
```

Solution 2 :  Set style locally

```
<div class="form-control">
    <div class="login-placeholder" style="color:#ccc;" @click="isAddShow=!isAddShow">{{ addrItem }}
    </div>
    <ul v-show="isAddShow" class="l-select-wrap" style="color:#000;">
        <li v-for="(item,i) in addSelectData" :key="i" @click="addSelectOption(item)"
            class="l-select-item">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Reference: [CSS Colors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors.asp)